# Lossless reproduce of Image in Java

Tags: java, api, image-processing, matrix

I am working on one sample Image algorithm, I would like to read complete image into matrix format and re-produce the same image with matrix data.

I was searching for similar api in Java, but couldn't find one.

If you read any image[MxN pixel] in matlab, it will be producing of image[m][n] size and in similar fashion, I would like to read and write the image into matrix/file in Java without any loss of data.

Comment: What do you want to use as input?

Comment: @Oswald, standard images [Jpg/png]

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean by loss of data, unless you mean the lossy jpeg compression. (if so, use png, which is not lossy).

Comment: @kiheru, you read an image into BufferedImage and write it to new file  ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", newFile); you will notice that the size of original file and this file differs and clearly you can see the difference between both pics.

Comment: Reddy: That is jpeg issue. The compression method throws away data. Use PNG instead.

Comment: @kiheru, here's the question for that. I am reading JPEG file and writing the duplicate of JPEG file, why data should be lost? don't we have any way to not to corrupt?

Comment: @kiheru, Lets say I read the image to matrix and rotate it by 90degree and save it as new file, which should be apparently rotated image of original image rather than lossing quality

Comment: It is the nature of the way jpeg stores data. There are tools that can do lossless rotation (and other, limited set of operations) to jpegs, but they do not manipulate the decompressed pixel data, but operate directly on the data blocks. For more complete explanation see for example [here](http://www.betterjpeg.com/lossless-rotation.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Image into a [java.awt.BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) a using one of the `read()` methods of [java.imageio.ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html). Then you can access the color values of each pixsel using [`getRGB(int x, int y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: Thanks for that. I am unable to write the data to Image without any loss of original image data. I updated my question too. I was able to read though, saving to file is losing the data